# Code Igniter: New project in a separate directory within the same domain

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to add a new project to my server. My server already has a project which is in the main root (public_html). Both projects were built using Code Igniter.
Now I added a new project which is in a folder called app2: Below is my folder structure:

```
-public_html
     - application
     - assets
     - system
     - app2 (the new project)
         - application
         - assets
         - system
```

My intent is for app2 project to be picked when the URL is as follows:

```
http://website.com/app2/...
```

I set up the base_url like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://website.com/'; //main project
$config['base_url'] = 'https://website.com/app2/'; //app2 project
```

The problem is that I get this error: Access denied for user 'the_db_user_for_app2'@'localhost' to database ' the_db_name_for_app2'
whenever I try the URL: https://website.com/app2/...
The password is very correct, and that makes me wonder if I'm actually doing the right thing. References to the first project works fine.

So that brings me to my question: what is the best way to add a new project in a separate directory (folder) within the same domain in Code Igniter (where the new project must have a separate database). I have one domain and I need to live test the new project (app2) I just finished building locally and I can't take down the first project from the server.

Comment: You need separate config.php and database.php files for both

Comment: Yes i know and did that. both projects have their own separate directories, sub-directories and files

Comment: _Access denied for user 'the_db_user_for_app2'@'localhost' to database ' the_db_name_for_app2'_ There is an error with your connection, make sure (double check) that username, password and host are correct.

Comment: Thanks Mehdi, your answer set me right. I mistakenly put an empty space before my db_name value in database config. Works fine. I'm glad to know I was actually on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `application`, `system` and `view` folders once again in inside the `/app2` directory.

You can point already exist directories with the same configuration in `/app2/index.php`

remove following directories

```
/app2/application
/app2/system
/app2/view
```

open `/app2/index.php` file find and replace the variables.

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
$view_folder = '../application/views';
```